# nodemon not restarting [isomorphic web app]

Tags: webpack, nodemon

I configured Webpack so that I can have live reloading both in front and back. Front part is working great but server reload is not working.

Basically, when I hit npm start (which runs "webpack-dev-server -d --hot --config webpack.config.js --watch") it creates my bundle.js and then onbuildend it launches nodemon. Nodemon is supposed to watch any changes in my src folder and in server.js.

webpack.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildEnd: ['nodemon -V --watch src server.js']})
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./views"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    host: 'localhost', // Defaults to `localhost`
    port: 3000, // Defaults to 8080
    watchContentBase: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  },
```

However, whenever I make any changes in my js files in src, nodemon does not restart and I can't see the changes.

OR I get "Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/signup from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNRESET)"

If, someone can help me to understand theses 2 issues it would be great! thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your js files compiled with webpack are served on localhost:3000 and nodemon is on 8080 port.
I assume you're using express, you should use webpack-dev-middleware & not not webpack-dev-server, this way you'll serve your react jsx/js and static files the same port as nodemon.
btw if you're running your app through a Docker container the launch CMD should contain the `-L` flag.

`nodemon -L server.js`

UPDATED:

**server.js**:

```
var express = require("express")
var path = require("path")

const PORT = 3000
const app = express()


//webpack
const webpack = require('webpack')
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
const config = require("./webpack.config.js");
const compiler = webpack(config);


// Tell express to use the webpack-dev-middleware and use the webpack.config.js
// configuration file as a base.
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true
  }
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

// static assets
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "./public"))



// main route
app.get("/", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"))
)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("App listening on port " + PORT))
```

**webpack.config.js :**

```
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: ["webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true","./src/index.jsx"],
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".css", ".scss"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: devMode ? "[name].css" : "[name].[hash].css",
      chunkFilename: devMode ? "[id].css" : "[id].[hash].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

**nodemon.json:**

```
{
    "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/**/node_modules"],
    "ext": "js,json,html"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, can you show an exanple?